# JQuery SlideDown() is delaying second half of a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

I have a simple *JQuery* thing that activates when the page is ready. Two strings would slide down at different times.

The problem is that in the first string, only the first half of the word slides down but the second half is delayed for a split second.

*Can someone tell me why?*

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>The KGV Connection</title>
<script src="../jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
.header{
 background-color:#007B4C;
 width:1280px;
 height:70px;
 position:fixed;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 z-index:10;
 }
    .body{
  width:1267px;
  position:relative;
  left:-12px;
  height:1010px;
  background-color:#EDF0F5;
  top:25px;
  z-index:9;
  }      
  .footer{
   background-color:#007B4C;
 width:1267px;
  position:relative;
  left:-12px;
 height:200px;
 top:25px;
 z-index:9;
   }              
               .message{
    font-family:"MS PGothic";
    width:1200px;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    left:50px;
    color:#333333;
    top:200px;
    display:none;
    }
            .congratulations{
    position:relative;
    font-family:"MS PGothic";
    width:300px;
    left:450px;
    top:200px;
    color:#333333;
    font-size:60px;
    display:none;
    }
            </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<img src="../Pictures/Logo.png" width="291" height="70" />
</div>
<div class="body">
<h1 class="congratulations">Congratulations!</h1>
<p class="message"><b>Your account has been successfully activated!</b></p>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".congratulations").slideDown(400);
 $(".message").delay(1000).slideDown(400);
});
</script>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Leuven Wang, do you need the css? should delete it otherwise for readability

Comment: Mmm, `<!DOCTYPE ... XHTML...>` with jQuery 2.x ... doesn't look like a good marriage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the **h1** element containing your string "Congratulations!" is smaller than it's rendered text and jQuery apparently applies the animation on the **h1** element at first, which crops just a fraction of the string.

Either remove **width** property of **.congratulations** class or make it wider than the text.

I suggest you to use "inspect elemnt" tool in your browser to debug strange things like this.

[image: Inspect element on h1 element]

Comment: Of all the exact same answers, I like this one. Can't beat an inspection screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for CONGRATULATIONS to cut out while sliding is because of the width given for `.congratulations` in CSS.
The first half that slides will be equal to the width that is set. Reducing would keep the first part smaller and increasing would keep it larger.
Keeping the `width:100%` is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

hi the problem comes from css class .congratulations
increase to width:500px //this will fix the problem with half word slide

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty wild, slideDown is sliding down only the portion you specified in the width, 300px. The rest is displayed after the slideDown finishes.

Remove width from congratulations CSS class.